# Zesty DNS resolution no longer accepts search domain setting from DHCP

Tags: network-manager, 17.04, dns, dhcp, systemd-resolved

This is on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 (fully updated), btw...

As we all know, Zesty's name resolution changed from dnsmasq (via NetworkManager) to systemd-resolved. One side effect (that apparently 17.10 already fixes) is that DNS resolution for local names (i.e. non-fqdn) only uses local MDNS, instead of using DHCP's DNS servers.

After much reading, I've come to realize that the problem here is due to systemd-resolved's default behavior.  However, all the remedies I've found mention creating a .network file with specific contents (see below), putting it in /etc/systemd/network, and re-starting.

This is what I've done so far:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/network/usedomains.network
[Match]
Name=en*

[DHCP]
UseDomains=yes
```

Now, I've tried it both with and without the [Match] section, as well as the specific ethernet interface name, MAC address, etc. No dice. Under no circumstances does the resolver pick up the domain setting from DHCP.

Needless to say I have other older boxes which have no such issue.

I believe the issue has to do with using NetworkManager to continue to manage the network stack, vs. using systemd-networkd - so apparently it's NetworkManager "somehow" failing to tell systemd-resolved that it should use the DHCP domains.

The reason I've been reluctant to switch to systemd-networkd is because I don't want to mess around too much with the default Ubuntu layout. In particular, I don't want to break the GUI-related stuff (what can I say? I've become lazy in my late years :D).

This is the current behavior (where the DHCP-configured DNS servers aren't used, and the DHCP-configured domain name isn't used as a search domain for local names):

```
# dig +short some-local-hostname
(no record found)
```

This is the desired behavior (where the DHCP-configured DNS servers are used, and the DHCP-configured domain name is used as a search domain for local names):

```
# dig +short some-local-hostname
192.168.XXX.XXX
```

So...anyone wish to chime in?  Any thoughts on how I might be able to fix this annoying little issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have U17.04 zesty and my IP is static.  This network does not have a DHCP server or IP Helper to a DHCP server, and Ubuntu's Global DNS Servers are Googles public 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  The /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file indicates these are the #FallbackDNS settings.  I was able to change mine to a local DNS server, remove the #, and reboot and resolve my local hostnames (that are not on this broadcast domain).

Also my systemd-resolve --status indicates the MulticastDNS setting is disabled and LLMNR/IPv4 and LLMNR/IPv6 LLMNR settings are enabled so you and I have slightly different situations (static vs dynamic IP) yet the apparently opposite systemd-resolve defaults.  You could modify your /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file to enable LLMNR.  Following which, Man for systemd-resolve indicates that by default the lookup is done via all protocols suitable for the lookup.

Hey thanks for posting "As we all know, Zesty's name resolution changed from dnsmasq (via NetworkManager) to systemd-resolved."  This helped me.